# How to get more usable screen area in the Salesforce mobile app on iPhones for Aura Components? Temporary full screen mode?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Some iPhones and iPhone SE do have very small screens. If you want to implement complex processes, every tiny bit of space on the screen is required and should not be wasted for non-functional or blank space.

Now I found that almost one third of the screen is blocked with not very useful stuff (at least for my custom process) marked in red.

I'm using an Aura Component. Is there a way to get a popup or full-screen-mode to temporarily make use of the full real estate the small screen has to offer? Can I hide or get rid of the header or footer for a while? One single X-button to close my component would be super nice.

I see that such an user interface is not very aligned with the rest of the UX, but ease of use for my power users would be highly appreciated. Buying new phones for a huge team is unfortunately no option. The target device is given: iPhone SE 3rd gen.

Any ideas?

I need no working code. Pure concepts or code fragments would be more than enough.

[image]